# Recursively apply the msgfmt command to all .po files in directory with find -exec

Tags: bash, scripts, find, msgfmt

I have the following directory structure:

```
webiste/
    locale/
        en/
             LC_MESSAGES/
                     translation.po
        de/
            LC_MESSAGES/
                     translation.po
        fr/
            LC_MESSAGES/
                     translation.po
```

I am using the `find` command to get to all the `.po` files and apply the `msgfmt` command to them.

So when I run this command:

```
find . -name \*.po
```

The output is

```
./locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/translation.po
./locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/translation.po
./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/translation.po
```

Just as expected but now I when I add this:

```
find . -name \*.po -exec msgfmt "{}" \;
```

It outputs nothing and it does not create the .mo files it is supposed to (If I do it to each file individually the `msgfmt` command works as expected).

This is weird since if I change the command to this:

find . -name *.po -exec echo "{}" \;

It outputs the names of the files correctly.

I've sort of solved it like this:

```
find . -name \*.po -exec msgfmt "{}" -o {}.mo \;
```

But it outputs a `translation.po.mo`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `-execdir`?

This differs from `-exec` in that it runs the command from the same directory that it finds the files (rather than the current working directory). Given that you're only going to find one `translation.po` file in your LC_MESSAGES directories, we can lock things right down and not have to fuss around trying to snap the extension off the end of the path.

```
find . -name \*.po -execdir msgfmt translation.po -o translation.mo \;
```

Comment: Awesome :) Works like a charm, I'll accept as soon as I can...

Answer (score 5):

I am using something like this:

```
find . -name \*.po -execdir sh -c 'msgfmt "$0" -o `basename $0 .po`.mo' '{}' \;
```

This also removes *.po extension and add *.mo extension.

More generaly (file names with spaces):

```
find locale_dir/ -name \*.po -print -execdir sh -c 'msgfmt -f -o "$(basename "$0" .po).mo" "$0"' '{}' \;
```